# $_SESSION['exist']=true even if not set

Tags: php, session

i'm about to update my website and since i have offshored some code it want work anymore...

My problem now is, that i want to update the stats, when a new user visits my site but it doesn't go into the if, because the `$_SESSION['exist']` is just true, even if not stated.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['exist'])){ //it doesn't go in this if
    $_SESSION['exist'] = true;

    $today = date("Y/m/d");
    require(__DIR__ . '/./functions/select/stats/daily_view.php');
    $dailyview = selectDailyView();
    echo $dailyview['date'];
    if($dailyview['date'] != $today){
        //start COPY
        $dv = selectDailyView();
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/./functions/insert/stats/dailyview.php');
        insertDailyView($dv[0]['date'], $dv[0]['dailyview']);
        //end COPY
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/./functions/update/stats/reset_daily_view.php');
        updateResetDailyviewDate($today);
    }

    require_once(__DIR__ . '/./functions/update/stats/stats.php');
    updateStat('index');

    require_once(__DIR__ . '/./functions/update/stats/dailyview.php');
    updateDailyView();
}
?>
```

So i tried to comment out everything except the `session_start();` and to see whats stored in the `$_SESSION` i wrote a `var_dump($_SESSION);` and it says

> array(1){["exist"]=>bool(true)}

I tried to clear the cache, unset the `$_SESSION`, destroy the session... Nothing worked. With `unset($_SESSION);` the output is *NULL*, but when i delete that line and reload the page the output still says

> array(1){["exist"]=>bool(true)}

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `unset($_SESSION)` doesn't unset all sessions. It just unsets that variable during that request. You need to unset the specific key (as the answer below already states). If that doesn't work either, then you probably are setting that session value somewhere before you check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `unset` it :

```
unset($_SESSION['exist']);
```